# How do i debug this USB-Serial connection?

Tags: python, pyserial

I am trying to talk to a Stanford Research Systems SR760 spectrum analyzer on my mac (10.7.5) via Serial, using a Serial-to-USB adapter to connect to my laptop. I am using the Prolific USB-serial driver. Not sure which but I installed it recently. It probably is the PL2303 one.

Using Python, here's some sample code

```
import time
import serial

# configure the serial connections (the parameters differs on the device you
# are connecting to)
ser = serial.Serial(
    port='/dev/cu.PL2303-0000201A',
    baudrate=19200,
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    rtscts=0,
    dsrdtr=0,
    timeout=2,
)

if ser.isOpen():
    ser.flushInput()
    ser.flushOutput()

    print """Enter your commands below.\r\nInsert "exit" to leave the
            application."""

    while 1:
        # get keyboard input
        input = raw_input(">> ")
        if input == 'exit':
            ser.close()
            exit()
        else:
            ser.write(input + '\r')
            out = ''
            # let's wait one second before reading output (let's give device
            # time to answer)
            lines = 0
            while 1:
                time.sleep(1)
                out = out + ser.readline()
                lines = lines + 1
                if lines > 5:
                    break
            print "read data: " + out
```

Using the SR760's manual, I send it: *IDN?, a basic "identify" command. I expect for something to pop up in my terminal, nothing does. It just times out. However, if I look at the send queue on the SR760, it will show the identity string, and in fact responds to a bunch of different commands. I'm just not getting anything on my computer and that is the problem. I know it is supposed to work that way because my colleague wrote code that words on his computer (a windows laptop).

How do I even start debugging this? I've tweaked the timeout, and confirmed the sr760 had the same parameters I was expecting.

Comment: Serial to USB can potentially have problems unrelated to your code... Have you tried a telnet session to ensure that works first?

Comment: Good suggestion by @MattCoubrough, but not sure how telnet is going to help here. You need a terminal emulator such as [PuTTY](http://www.putty.org/) or `minicom` equivalents for Mac etc. If you get no joy from that, check that your serial cable is wired correctly.

Comment: Sorry, meant terminal session, not telnet session. I endorse PuTTY as my emulator of choice too... Not saying there isn't a problem with the code - but its best to make sure a terminal session works first before going to lengths debugging!

Comment: @user2072848 is on Mac, so he/she already has a decent Terminal app. And even minicom, here's the tutorial: http://pbxbook.com/other/mac-tty.html

Comment: The idea is to check if the device communication with computer works at all.